# The number of TCP connections when using HTTP keep-alive and websockets (socket.io)

Tags: http, tcp, websocket, socket.io, keep-alive

I have implemented a full-fledged node http server with database-driven sesssion management and have been able to use socket.io on top for implementing file upload progress bar and a chat application.
I have also used node-http-proxy and was able to proxy websockets.  Against, this background I have the following questions which I believe I need to know to be an effective socket.io developer. I am not stuck in any specific code but the information requested below is a MUST to be a effective sockets developer but does not appear to be explained anywhere.

My understanding:

a. HTTP uses a TCP socket as the underlying transport. 
   In older HTTP implementations, one socket was used per request.
   In newer ones, the "Keep-alive" header is used to keep the socket alive for use with multiple request-response.
   TCP is inherently full-duplexed, both in its signalling and data transfer, but not multiplexed in the sense that multiple HTTP request/response cannot be loaded on the same connection at the same time. The keep-alive flag helps to use the same connection, for http request/response transactions in sequence.

b. The "upgrade" HTTP header is used to upgrade a regular http connection to a websocket one. A websocket connection is effectively the basic TCP connection which is now abstracted at the http protocol level.

Question: After the websockets handshake, are there two TCP connections now or just one that is used by http for full-duplex communication?
   I mean, is there one TCP connection for the regular http requests and another one now for bi-directional transfer that libraries like socket.io use?
   In other words, does the header "upgrade" truly means upgrade of an existing TCP connection and not the opening of a new one?
   Can one webpage open multiple ws-based TCP connections to the same server? For example, two chat sessions in the same page managed by the same server?
   In this case, what will be the total number of open TCP connections and of what type will they be?

I tried to get some answers with netstat but I could not arrive at any definite conclusions. Wireshark may be helpful but I am not adept at using it.
Any clarification will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A websocket connection is effectively the basic TCP connection which is now abstracted at the http protocol level.

HTTP is a protocol on top of TCP and WebSockets is also a protocol on top of TCP. While WebSockets look from the programming side mostly like normal sockets it is not pure TCP. Instead there is some  framing to get message boundaries instead of a single data stream and some masking of the data so stupid proxies does not get refused in case HTTP like things are transmitted using WebSockets.

The HTTP upgrade switches the protocol of the underlying TCP connection from HTTP to the Websockets protocol. Once the switch is done there is no way back.

> Can one webpage open multiple ws-based TCP connections to the same server?

A web page can open multiple HTTP connections to the same server and each of these can be upgraded  to WebSockets. The only limitation from the Websockets RFC is that the browser should not create multiple Websockets connection at the same time to the same host, but there is no limitation that they are created after each other and run in parallel.

> In this case, what will be the total number of open TCP connections and of what type will they be?

This depends on your application. There will be a TCP connection for each WebSockets connection. Additionally there will be other TCP connections to get the HTTP resources. The exact type of these (HTTP vs. HTTP/2) and how many these are depends on browser and server, i.e. if keep-alive is used, HTTP/2 is used etc.

Comment: Upvoted. As HTTP is effectively request-driven, how can it be used by websockets to implement communication initiated by the server? Also, if two ws connections cannot be initiated by the browser to the same host, does that mean that there cannot be, for example, two ws-based chats from the same host in the same application running at the same time in a browser? After an upgrade, does regular http request use the upgraded protocol or is still able to use the underlying plain-vanilla http?  This clarification will complete the answer and will be useful to others too.

Comment: @Samir: The browser can have multiple Websockets connections to the same host, it should only not create them at the same time (but once created they continue to run). Also, Websockets are effectively a  transport layer protocol prefixed by an HTTP request and is not limited to the request-response scheme. This is similar to a CONNECT request which is used to tunnel HTTPS (and Websockets) through a HTTP proxy.

Comment: I have accepted the answer but here are some final doubts, if you can spare some time. "Also, Websockets are effectively a transport layer protocol prefixed by an HTTP request and is not limited to the request-response scheme." So, HTTP is used only for the initial handshake and then does not play a role in websockets? Are regular HTTP requests serviced after the upgrade the same way as before the upgrade?

Comment: @Samir: there are no regular HTTP requests in the same connection after the upgrade is done. Once you are upgraded to Websockets there is no way back. This is also similar to CONNECT request. The whole concept is similar to a multi-stage rocket. You can get only from first stage (HTTP) to second (Websockets) but not back.

Comment: I consider adding the following points: 1. Using `keep-alive` doesn't guaranty a single HTTP connection (newer browsers will use 2-4 connections to avoid large responses blocking the flow of information, older ones would use more). 2. after the `upgrade`, the connection is Websocket Protocol over TCP/IP, NOT HTTP (I think you wrote HTTP by mistake at the end of your first paragraph). 3. There's no way back to HTTP unless opening a new connection. 4. There is no way to guaranty how many connections each client will utilize, especially when factoring socket.io's behavior.

Comment: @Myst: to 2) HTTP is over TCP/IP and WebSockets just continues to use the same underlying TCP/IP connection. But WebSockets is not plain TCP/IP. There is an additional framing to get messages not strings and there is also XORing so that stupid proxies do not get confused.

Comment: @Myst: as for 1) and 4) - while these are true I don't think they are part of the question the OP had. And as for 2) and 3) - I reworked the answer to make these points more clear.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - as for 2) I know about the extra framing (I'm the author of Iodine, [Plezi's](http://www.plezi.io) websocket and HTTP server)... But there is no longer any Hyper Text Transfer Protocol (i.e. request->response), so we leave HTTP behind, communicating using the websocket protocol (i.e. framing & masking) over TCP/IP. The same is true when upgrading from HTTP to HTTP/2 (`htc`) or when using ALPN - we leave the old protocol behind in favor of the new one. Hence, it's no longer HTTP, although it is the same TCP/IP connection.

Comment: @Myst: I agree with you and I think after the editing I've done this should be more clear. And I did my websockets protocol implementation too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - Yap, clearer. It a very clear an concise answer. As for (1) & (4), I would consider referencing the info at the end, when you answer the total number of connections that is being used. Your answer seems to refer to the final state, but ignores the connections used while the browser loads the resources. Anyway, you have my vote :-)

Comment: @Myst  The points that "newer browsers will use 2-4 connections to avoid..." and "so we leave HTTP behind, communicating using the websocket protocol... over TCP/IP..."  truly adds value to the accepted answer.

Comment: @Samir: but the exact details depend on the browser and the server. The server may not use keep-alive, may offer HTTP/2 and the numbers of parallel connections [depend on the browser](http://sgdev-blog.blogspot.de/2014/01/maximum-concurrent-connection-to-same.html) and of course how many resources are needed to get etc. Wide variations are possible.

Comment: This is a valuable question and its answers and comments are also great! I came to here for a similar one: If Keep-alive presents and only one TCP connection is in use, and several files, say, css files and js files are transmitting, and one js file starts a WebSocket while there some more files to be transmitted, then what about the rest transmission? If the TCP connection upgrades to WS immediately then what about the rest files to be transmitted in HTTP? I guess browse implementation won't reuse the TCP connection for a Keep-alive HTTP channel. However I haven't proved it.

Comment: @Robert: the comment section is not the right place to ask new questions, even related ones. Only very few will notice the question there and nobody would look in the comments for the answer.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for your tip. I'll think about it and ask later.